# Chunking a CLOB over a DB Link

Tags: oracle, clob, dblink

We have used this procedure (borrowed), and it has worked great.

```
create or replace function fn_dblink_clob(
    p_dblink    in varchar2
  , v_remote_table in varchar2
  , p_clob_col  in varchar2
  , p_rid       in urowid
)
return clob is
    /**  A function to fetch a CLOB column over a dblink  **/
    /**  Laurence Prescott 25-Aug-17  **/
    /**  select dblink_clob('some_dblink', 'some_clob_column', rowid)
           from some_table@some_dblink;
         Note: Does not work on tables that have a virtual column (eg. xmltype).
    **/

    c_chunk_size    constant pls_integer := 4000;
    v_chunk         varchar2(5000);
    v_clob          clob;
    v_pos           pls_integer := 1;
begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob, true, dbms_lob.call);
    loop
        execute immediate 
            'select dbms_lob.substr@' ||p_dblink|| '(' ||p_clob_col|| ', ' ||c_chunk_size
         || ', ' ||v_pos|| ') from ' ||v_remote_table|| '@' ||p_dblink|| ' where rowid = :rid '
        into v_chunk using p_rid;
        begin dbms_lob.append(v_clob, v_chunk);
        exception when others then
            if sqlcode = -6502 then exit; else raise; end if;
        end;
        if length(v_chunk) < c_chunk_size then exit; end if;
        v_pos := v_pos + c_chunk_size;
    end loop;
    return v_clob;
end fn_dblink_clob;
```

We normally point this to a physical table, but now need to point to a VIEW.

I can take what the code is doing effectively and run this statement to return a CLOB over a DB Link, it works fine.

```
select dbms_lob.substr@ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB(NARRATIVE, 4000,1) from ARGUS_CUSTOM.dlp_case_narrative_rowid@ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB where row_id = 'AAATVIAIpAAABzOAAD'
```

When I try and run the function as part of a SQL statement:

```
  select 
    ROW_ID, 
    CASE_ID, 
    fn_dblink_clob('ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB', 'ARGUS_CUSTOM.dlp_case_narrative_rowid','NARRATIVE', NARR.ROW_ID) as NARRATIVE
  
 from ARGUS_CUSTOM.dlp_case_narrative_rowid@ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB NARR
```

I get this:

```
ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
ORA-02063: preceding line from ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB
ORA-06512: at "PV_COMPLIANCE.FN_DBLINK_CLOB", line 22
01446. 00000 -  "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So there are no distinct or group by clauses in the view.  And what the function does dynamically is build up the statement which I know execute against this view fine.

Base view definition on remote machine, has no joins, no group by or distinct clauses.

```
CREATE VIEW DLP_CASE_NARRATIVE_ROWID
    AS 
SELECT ROWID AS "ROW_ID", "CASE_ID",
"ABBREV_NARRATIVE",
"DELETED",
"NARRATIVE",
"ABBREV_NARRATIVE_J",
"NARRATIVE_J",
"DLP_REVISION_NUMBER",
"EFFECTIVE_START_DATE",
"EFFECTIVE_END_DATE",
"DELETED_FLAG",
"ENTERPRISE_ID" FROM DLP_OWNER.DLP_CASE_NARRATIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a ROWID (aliased as row_id) exposed explicitly in your view. Just use that... query against row_id instead of rowid.

```
execute immediate 
            'select dbms_lob.substr@' ||p_dblink|| '(' ||p_clob_col|| ', ' ||c_chunk_size
         || ', ' ||v_pos|| ') from ' ||v_remote_table|| '@' ||p_dblink|| ' where row_id = :rid '
        into v_chunk using p_rid;
```

FYI, I have done the same thing you are doing - create a procedure that chunks LOBs for faster processing over dblinks. I did it differently though, I placed the procedure on the remote database, and I pass in a collection of ROWIDs. The procedure reads the CLOBs into a local collection, converts them to BLOBs, compresses them, then chunks them out into a collection of RAW, returns that collection as an OUT parameter to the caller, which is a procedure on the local database. That procedure reverses the process, reassembles the BLOBs from the collection of RAW, decompresses, converts to CLOBs, then updates the target table with the CLOB values. For the same reason you have encountered, I also do not support pulling from a complex view, because my code needs the ROWIDs from the source. But the solution is to rewrite the view so that it only has one table at the top level, all other joins being done by subquery.

I also have a first-pass mechanism that pulls as VARCHAR2(4000) (via CAST) any CLOB that is under that size. That's much faster than pulling them as CLOBs. But that still requires the ROWID.

Also I should note that while this gave me considerable performance gains 10+ years ago over Oracle's native LOB-over-dblink back in the days of 10g-11g, in recent versions I have found that they've tweaked their internal processing and native LOB transfers are much faster now, so it may not longer be worth this kind of hacky workaround.

Comment: Hi, view is straight select from single table.  I can select clobs over dblinks, I just can’t then turn that select statement into a view as it complains about remote lob references.  19C.  Why I can select a clob,  but can’t then turn the select into a view is a mystery, hence the hack

Comment: Added the base view, no groups bys, joins or distincts

Comment: Edited my answer after seeing your view... since the view exposes ROWID explicitly, you can use that column (row_id with the underscore). To generalize it you may want to add the rowid column name to your proc parameters. If you still get an error, check to see if the underlying object (DLP_CASE_NARRATIVE) is *also* a view and then look at that view code to see what you can do.

Comment: I am using ROW_ID if you look at the function parameter I am passing:  fn_dblink_clob('ARGUS_TRANSCT_DB', 'ARGUS_CUSTOM.dlp_case_narrative_rowid','NARRATIVE', NARR.ROW_ID) as NARRATIVE

Comment: Not there.. that's passing in the actual content of the ROW_ID column into your proc... I'm talking about referencing the column name ROW_ID *inside* the proc, in the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE... see the end of my answer.

Comment: Ah.....let me try that